# Обработка big data, оптимизация сортировки

Tags: c#, сортировка, оптимизация, циклы

Имеется входной файл ~ 1млн строк, которые должны сортироваться по определенному принципу.
На данный момент сортировка происходит следующим образом:

```
        int wk;
        while (Objects.Count() != 0)
        {
            SortRow.Add(Objects.ElementAt(0));
            Objects.RemoveAt(0);

            for (wk = 0; wk < Objects.Count(); wk++)
            {
                if (Objects.ElementAt(wk).F1 == SortRow.ElementAt(0).F1)
                {
                    SortRow.Add(Objects.ElementAt(wk));
                    Objects.RemoveAt(wk);
                    wk--;
                }

            }
            SortMas.Add(SortRow);
            SortRow = new List<line>();
        }
        progressBar1.Maximum = SortMas.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < SortMas.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < SortMas[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                if (SortMas[i][j].F57 == 32 &&
                    (Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j].F39) < Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j - 1].F39)))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        line a = SortMas[i][j];
                        SortMas[i][j] = SortMas[i][j - 1];
                        SortMas[i][j - 1] = a;
                        j--;
                        if (j == 0) break;
                    }
                    while ((Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j].F39) < Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j - 1].F39)));
                }

                if ((SortMas[i][j].F57 != 32) &&
           (Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j].F58) < Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j - 1].F58))
           && SortMas[i][j - 1].F57 != 32)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        line a = SortMas[i][j];
                        SortMas[i][j] = SortMas[i][j - 1];
                        SortMas[i][j - 1] = a;
                        j--;
                        if (j == 0) break;
                    }
                    while ((Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j].F58) < Convert.ToInt32(SortMas[i][j - 1].F58)
                    && SortMas[i][j - 1].F57 != 32));
                }
            }
        }
```

Проблема в том, что сортировка происходит катастрофически медленно. Каким образом можно это дело оптимизировать?

Comment: "сортироваться по определенному принципу" - лучше опишите сам принцип. Может быть не придется изобретать свой велосипед и такая реализация уже существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть какой то тип:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string F1 { get; }
    public string F39 { get; }
    public int F57 { get; }        
    public string F58 { get; }
}
```

как я понял SortMas у вас `List<List<MyType>>`

В таком случае вы можете написать свой IComparer

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<MyType>
{
    public int Compare(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        if (y.F57 == 32)
            return int.Parse(x.F39).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.F39));

        if(x.F57 != 32 && y.F57 != 32)
            return int.Parse(x.F58).CompareTo(int.Parse(y.F58));

        return 0;
    }
}
```

И использовать стандартную сортировку, то есть часть под

```
progressBar1.Maximum = SortMas.Count();
```

Будет выглядеть так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SortMas.Count; i++)
   SortMas[i] = SortMas[i].OrderBy(x => x, new CustomComparer()).ToList();
```